# I want to return an error message using Sweet alert going through my Laravel controller

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, sweetalert2

I want to return an error message using Sweet alert going through my Laravel controller.

**Controller**

```
public function update(TenderRequest $request,$id)
{
    $tender = TenderMaster::findOrFail($id);

    if($request->extend_date < $request->end_date){
    //Return error message here
    }
}
```

**Sweet Alert Function:**

```
error: function (data) {
    var errors = data.responseJSON;
    //console.log(errors.message.errors);
    $.each(errors.errors,function (k,v) {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Error!',
            html:
            '<h4><code>' + v + '</code></h4>',
            confirmButtonText: 'Close',
            confirmButtonColor: '#d33',
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this...

```
   return Response::json([('status' => 'success','data'=>'data')]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go back with `back()` function and add the error as usual:

```
if($request->extend_date < $request->end_date){
     Alert::error('Error Message', 'Optional Title');
     return redirect()->back();
}
else ...
```

Answer (score 0):

i hop i got you well.
you can do this

```
return response()->with('error','data');
```